# I face differences on IE and chrome

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I face some layout differences in IE and in Chrome. I have searched Stack overflow high and low for solutions and tried some of it... I tried setting box-sizing to initial...it did not work...there fore  tried setting height of the text box it did work but still a big differences. I also tried changing doctype to strict. I encounter this problem as part of my project.

The Problem:
I have form in a div tag. In the form there are 4 rows of text field. I put the preview on IE and the preview on Chrome side by side to compare and realise that it is the spacing between the text area that causes the differences in height.

The Code on my html file:

```
  <div class="leftdetails">
    <form class="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
      <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="regfields"/>
      <br />
      <label for="cdsid">CDSID: </label>
      <input type="text" name="cdsid" id="cdsid" class="regfields"/>
      <br />
      <label for="mail">Mail Drop: </label>
      <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="regfields"/>
      <br />
     <label for="dateofbirth">D.O.B.: </label>
     <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" class="regfields"/>
     <br />
    </form>
  </div>
```

The code on my CSS (external)

```
    .leftdetails
    {
font-family:Myriad Pro;
font-size:18px;
float:left;
width:50%;
text-align:center;
    }

    .regfields
    {
width:200px;
height:20px;
vertical-align:bottom; 
    }

     .form2
    {
text-align:right;
margin-right:50px;
    }
```

This is not published online yet therefore there is not link...but I will be glad to provide screenshot. Its a very minor difference but I just want to understand why.

Comment: You can't really 'upload' images to SO. You CAN use an image host, (such as [imgur](http://imgur.com) ) to host images, and then use the `<img>` tag in your post, to link to it.

Comment: @PenguinCoder I add the screenshot...thanks

Comment: It would be beneficial to see an actual screenshot. You might also want to trace the rendered styles of your text fields through Firebug or a similar tool. It might just be a case of different default margins/borders/paddings between browsers.

Comment: @holodoc will i be able to fix the problem if it is by default margins/paddings/borders between browser?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: did you try to set the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to 0px in the `regfields` CSS class. Maybe also `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Comment: @JScoobyCed OMG!!! THANKS THANKS YOU SOLVE MY PROBLEM!!!! thank You...

Comment: Welcome. I added the answer so you can mark this question answered.

Comment: "Just want to understand why", then allow me to answer you in picture form:
http://cdn2.mixrmedia.com/wp-uploads/ziggytek/blog/2011/06/browser-wars.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to 0px in the `regfields` CSS class. Maybe also `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a conditional IE statement in your CSS to target only the Internet Explorer browser.

If you don't know how to do so, examples can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)